# Baseline existing database

Tags: sqitch

Im looking at Sqitch and so far it seems like a great tool, however I have an existing project that I want to use it with, Is there a way to create a baseline?

For example, I take a backup of my schema then add it to the deploy script, I then want to run a command that will not run the this script on the database as it already exists, but would apply everything after this point?

I need the full base schema in there so that we can re-deploy the whole schema if required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--log-only` option of `sqitch deploy` command

From the docs: https://sqitch.org/docs/manual/sqitch-deploy/

> --log-only
>
> Log the changes as if they were deployed, but without actually running the deploy scripts. Useful for an existing database that is being converted to Sqitch, and you need to log changes as deployed because they have been deployed by other means in the past.